# Не находит Unity UnityEngine.UI и UnityEngine.EventSystems в Visual Studio Code, Unity 2019.3

Tags: unity3d-editor

```
Тип или имя пространства имен "UI" не существует в пространстве имен "UnityEngine" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку). [Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0234)
```

Эти классы UnityEngine.UI, UnityEngine.EventSystems в Unity 2019.3.3f1 Устарели. Чем их можно заменить?

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public Text text;
public Button previousButton;
public Dropdown dropdown;

public GraphicRaycaster graphicRaycaster;
public EventSystem eventSystem;
```

Comment: Они не устарели, у вас сломался проект. Вы случаем не VSCode используете?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Пишет во всех и на работе и дома Unity, что нет такой библиотеки ... Что делать тогда ?

Comment: Я вопрос выше поправил. У вас между работой и дома как проект синхронизируется? git?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да но все библитеки и прочее не копируются ....только Ассеты

Comment: В каком IDE работаете? В 2019.3 версии много репортов, что файлы именно проекта ломаются с VSCode и их нужно просто перегенерировать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker 2020 (version 1.44)  Visual Studio Code IDE

Comment: Добавил ответ, должно сработать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Довольно распространенная проблема именно в VSCode. Неизвестно, с чьей стороны проблема, VSCode или Unity, Unity на багтрекере пометила это как "Not Reproducible".

Решение:

1. Зайдите в Package Manager
2. Найдите Visual Studio Code Editor среди установленный расширений
3. Измените версию на **1.1.4** (если не заработает - попробуйте 1.1.3)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Убедитесь, что в External tools в Unity стоит `Generate all .csproj files`:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Закройте Unity
6. Удалите все `.csproj` и `.sln`
7. Запустите Unity, произойдет генерация файлов проекта с нуля, ассеты и все длругие файлы не пропадут

Comment: Красного нет ...Вроде все заработало

Comment: Версия 1.1.4   Поставил галочку Generate all .csproj files Перезапустил unity и заработало! Спасибо.

Comment: @clm я сам сидел с 1.1.4, но на ней не всегда этот способ срабатывал