# Помогите пожалуйста. Создаю игру. Всё было хорошо до того как начал писать скрипт.(создаю в Unity язык C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добавляю скрипт к объекту выдаёт ошибку. Имена классов совпадают. Делал по этому видео уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbvZ0HWDi9E&t=304s ( Имя ошибки can't add script component because the script class cannot be found)[[image: 1]

Comment: [гляньте это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713497/cant-add-script-component-because-the-script-class-cannot-be-found)

Comment: У вас ошибка в скрипте. Из-за неё он не скомпилируется и соответственно вы не сможете его добавить

Answer (score 3):

Как вы можете видеть в вашем скрипте есть ошибка. Вы не можете повесить на объект скрипт с ошибкой. Нужно ее устранить.

---

Касаемо ее устранения можете почитать здесь: [Не находит Unity UnityEngine.UI и UnityEngine.EventSystems в Visual Studio Code, Unity 2019.3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1107753/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-unity-unityengine-ui-%D0%B8-unityengine-eventsystems-%D0%B2-visual-studio-code)

Кратко: 
1. Зайдите в Package Manager
2. Найдите Visual Studio Code Editor среди установленный расширений
3. Измените версию на 1.1.4 (если не заработает - попробуйте 1.1.3)
4. Убедитесь, что в External tools в Unity стоит Generate all .csproj files
5. Закройте Unity
6. Удалите все .csproj и .sln
7. Запустите Unity, произойдет генерация файлов проекта с нуля, ассеты и все другие файлы не пропадут

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я ещё версию Unity поменял. У меня новая была.